# Disappearing SEHException

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have a C/C++ DLL. I have and ASP.NET application calling this DLL with P/Invoke. Sometimes one of this calls throws an `SEHException`.

Right now for testing purposes I call the function with the same data before anything else.

```
DllFunctions.MyStructure[] structArray = new DllFunctions.MyStructure[2];
structArray[0].A = 10;
structArray[0].B = 10;
structArray[0].C = 15;
structArray[0].D = 15;
structArray[1].A = 8;
structArray[1].B = 12;
structArray[1].C = 13;
structArray[1].D = 17;
int arraySize = 2;
DllFunctions.MyStructure[] otherArray = new DllFunctions.MyStructure[0];
DllFunction.ProblematicFunction(structArray, arraySize, otherArray, 0);
```

When I start the application in debug mode sometimes it happens to throw me the `SEHException`, sometimes it doesn't. What can cause random looking behaviour like this?

**EDIT**: The function runs fine if called from a C++ console application with the same data.

**EDIT**: the P/Invoke signature

```
[DllImport("mylib.dll")]
public extern static MyStructure ProblematicFunction(MyStructure[] structs1, int arrayLen1, MyStructure[] structs2, int arrayLen2);
```

Comment: Invoking UB, Undefined Behavior in C or C++ code doesn't typically require using C#.  Anything can happen, what you describe is not uncommon.  Rough on C# programmers because the language has little UB.  Solving it does require debugging the native code, get that started by ticking the "Enable unmanaged code debugging" option in the Project + Properties, Debug tab and setting a breakpoint on the native code.  Use unit tests to flush out bugs in a repeatable manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting an application in Debug mode disables the Low-Fragmentation Heap - you're still corrupting memory, you're just getting lucky and trashing some padding memory. If you want to see the normal behavior, run the app using Ctrl-F5, then Attach To Process with another VS instance

Comment: I must do something wrong, but this way it seems if all of my exceptions aren't even there. (I had another `AccessViolationException` in another function too.) But somehow I think they actually didn't get fixed.

Comment: You need to debug `ProblematicFunction` to see where it is raising the exception. The fact that the last parameter is a zero-length array suggests that it's not handling this boundary case correctly.

Comment: The function runs fine if called from a C++ console application with the same data. I'll edit that back to the question.

Comment: You may have a bad P/Invoke signature which is trashing the stack.

Comment: But then the stack should be trashed all the time. Or can the stack be padding memory too?

Comment: Parts of the stack will be padding, yes - other times, you still are trashing slots, but those slots happen to be unused, or you just got lucky and avoid a crash. This is what is so frustrating about debugging P/Invoke failures, it's highly likely that you can end up "working" some of the time